# Connect a CIFS network drive automatically

Tags: macos, network, vpn, cifs

Is there a way to connect a network server ([CIFS](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc939973.aspx)) without asking for password and would automatically connect every time computer boots up?

The situation is, the computer need to first connect its VPN (Cisco AnyConnect) and then connect the drive. But the thing is, most of the time it doesn't connect the drive and displays an error that the server is unavailable (which I think it displays because of the network connection) but, when I ping the IP address of the network drive while simultaneously connect the shared drive it connects!

What do I need to do?